# Integration Help

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

So I have to integrate $$\frac{\sin^n x}{\sin^n x + \cos^n x}$$ and am coding this in *Mathematica* with

```
 (((Sin^n)[x])/(((Sin^n)[x]) + ((Cos^n)[x])))
```

with the bounds $0$ and $\pi/2,$ where $n$ takes on various integer values.

I programmed the problem so that $n=1$ then $n=2$, etc...but every time I try to get the output, I only get back the integration symbol. For example, if I program $n=2$ and then do the integration command- the output is

```
 (((Sin^2)[x])/(((Sin^2)[x]) + ((Cos^2)[x]))),
```

but does not solve it. Anyone know how to help or fix this??

---

*Update:* Even with the syntax fixed, *Mathematica* does not solve it, with or without assumptions:

```
Integrate[Sin[x]^n/(Sin[x]^n + Cos[x]^n), {x, 0, Pi/2},
 Assumptions -> n > 0 && n \[Element] Integers]
```

Comment: Hello! It seems that you haven't included any code. Can you please include that here in the post? Based on your textual description my guess is that you are using `(Sin^2)[x]` when that syntax is incorrect, you should instead write it as `Sin[x]^2`

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82489/how-to-compute-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin3-t-sin3-t-cos3-tdt

Comment: Was it closed simply because of a syntax error by the OP? The integral with fixed syntax can be evaluated at specific values for `n`, as shown in two of the answers, but it cannot be evaluated with a unspecified parameter `n`. (Of course we often get this kind of question, which reveals limitiations of `Integrate`.)

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
Table[Integrate[Sin[x]^n/(Sin[x]^n+Cos[x]^n),{x,0,Pi/2}],{n,1,5}]
```

And it gives the output {Pi/4,Pi/4,Pi/4,Pi/4,Pi/4}.

[image]

Comment: Recommend that you add a `Plot` to make it easier to understand why the result is a constant.

Comment: Good suggestion. Editing.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're writing your function in the wrong format Emma. The following works fine:

```
n = 2;
Integrate[Sin[x]^n/(Sin[x]^n + Cos[x]^n),{x, 0, π/2}]
```

> `π/4`

Comment: I believe you have the parentheses in the wrong place relative to the original question. Right idea for the solution, though.

Comment: Yes, just realized that, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

A common trick (see [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82489/how-to-compute-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin3-t-sin3-t-cos3-tdt)):

$$\int_a^b f(x) \; dx \ 
 {\buildrel x = a+b-u \over =} -\int_b^a f(a + b - u) \; du
 = \int_a^b f(a + b - x) \; dx\, ,$$
so therefore
$$\int_a^b f(x) \; dx = \int_b^a {f(x) + f(a + b - x) \over 2} \; dx\, .$$

```
ClearAll[symmetrizeIntegrate];
SetAttributes[symmetrizeIntegrate, HoldAll];
symmetrizeIntegrate[Integrate[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, opts___]] := 
 Integrate[(f + (f /. x -> a + b - x))/2, {x, a, b}, opts]

symmetrizeIntegrate[Integrate[Sin[x]^n/(Sin[x]^n + Cos[x]^n), {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}]]
(*  π/4  *)
```