# Making a substitution within a typeset integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

This question derives directly from [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79152/finding-simplifying-substitutions-for-an-integral-involving-limits-and-integrand), but concerns instead a different matter... one related to display format.

This integral

$$I = \int\limits_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{\log (9-x)}}{\sqrt{\log (9-x)}+\sqrt{\log (x+3)}} \, dx$$

cannot be solved directly by *Mathematica*:

```
Integrate[
     Sqrt[Log[9 - x]]/(Sqrt[Log[9 - x]] + Sqrt[Log[x + 3]]), 
     {x, 2, 4}]
```

As shown in the linked problem, if you give *Mathematica* a substitution hint (based on the symmetry of the terms in the integrand), then it *can* solve the integral:

```
Integrate[
    Sqrt[Log[9 - x]]/(Sqrt[Log[9 - x]] + Sqrt[Log[x + 3]]) /. 
    {x -> y + 3}, 
    {y, -1, 1}]
```

(* 1 *)

I strongly prefer to display my input in mathematical typography (with integral signs and such),

[image]

How does one assert the change in variables (above) *in the mathematical typography* that shows integral signs and such?  I could go in *by hand* and replace the limits on the integral, the arguments in the integrand, and so on, but that seems very awkward indeed.

I've tried the rather obvious tricks based on `Assuming` and `Replace` and so on, but none work, for example

[image: Integral with replace rule]

Of course this particular integral is just an example.  I'd like a general approach.

Comment: Probably the following: `int1 = Inactive[Integrate][Sqrt[Log[9 - x]]/(Sqrt[Log[9 - x]] + Sqrt[Log[x + 3]]), {x, 2, 4}];  int2 = ReplacePart[MapAt[ReplaceAll[#, x -> y + 3] &, int1, {1}], 2 -> {y, -1, 1}];  int2//Activate` is not what you are looking for. Am I right?

Comment: Although helpful, you're right:  that's not what I'm seeking.  I must SEE the integral sign.  Motivation:  I make *Mathematica* presentations in front of my class, and I want the students to *see* mathematical typography to better think as *mathematicians* rather than code and computer scientists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the new in V 13.1 [IntegrateChangeVariables](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegrateChangeVariables.html)

```
int = Inactive[Integrate][Sqrt[Log[9 - x]]/(Sqrt[Log[9 - x]] + Sqrt[Log[x + 3]]), {x, 2, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
IntegrateChangeVariables[int, y, y == x - 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Activate[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> How does one assert the change in variables (above) in the
> mathematical typography

I do not know if the above does what you want, as the change of variable is done internally.

But if you want to display the step in Latex, then you could do

```
TeXForm[HoldForm[
  IntegrateChangeVariables[
   Inactive[Integrate][
    Sqrt[Log[9 - x]]/(Sqrt[Log[9 - x]] + Sqrt[Log[x + 3]]), {x, 2, 
     4}], y, y == x - 3]]]
```

Which compiles to

[image]

I would manually edit the Latex and remove `IntegrateChangeVariables` in final version (if you do not want it) which gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much.  I should have mentioned that I run v. 11.3, but this `IntegrateChangeVariables` looks so useful that I guess I'll upgrade.  I'm not interested in $\LaTeX$ here (but thanks anyway!), rather *Mathematica* typography where the integral sign is visible (rather than `Integrate[...]`.  I like to show math symbols in my class lectures to help my students think about *math* rather than *coding*.  The short answer (thanks):  Yes... this is all solved in v. 13... so I must upgrade.  ($\checkmark$)

Answer (score 5):

Since your concern is primarily with display, an approach focused on display using [`IntegrateChangeVariables`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegrateChangeVariables.html) recommended by Nasser:

```
$Version

"13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"

Clear["Global`*"]

Column[{"Expression to be integrated",
   eqn1 =
    f[x] == Sqrt[Log[9 - x]]/(Sqrt[Log[9 - x]] + Sqrt[Log[x + 3]]),
   "\nIntegrating",
   eqn2 = ApplySides[Inactive[Integrate][#, {x, 2, 4}] &, eqn1],
   "\nChange of variables",
   ConditionalExpression[(eqn3 = 
        ReplacePart[
         eqn2, -1 -> IntegrateChangeVariables[eqn2[[-1]], y, #]]), #] &[
    y == x - 3],
   "\nEvaluating",
   eqn4 = ReplacePart[eqn3, -1 -> Activate[eqn3[[-1]]]],
   "\nResult",
   eqn5 = ReplacePart[eqn4, {1, 1} -> eqn1[[-1]]]}] //
 TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: Nice typography... above and beyond the call of duty!  ($+1$). The core needed functionality was covered by Nasser, however.